# Email templates emoji digits not supported on Samsung mobiles and Firefox

Tags: html, html-email, emoji, mjml

I am building an email template which includes various emojis and some of them aren't supported on some mobile devices and Firefox.

The email template has to be compatible on all devices (including desktop browsers).

The problem I have is with digit emojis, for example [this one](https://emojipedia.org/keycap-digit-five/). I was wondering if using images instead of the not supported emojis is the only solution here.

I am using mjml framework for building the template.

Thanks :)

Comment: Please post a code example of what you tried so far.

Comment: Each device has its own way of rendering emojis. Gmail renders same emoji different if you put one in subject line and same in preheader or body. If you want uniform, then stick to images.